# Difference in Array Notation in Bash

Tags: bash

What's the difference between these two array notations?

- `"${aws_user_roles[@]}"`
- `"${aws_user_roles[*]}"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/1068283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in `man bash`

> If subscript is @ or *, the word expands  to  all  members  of name. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted, `${name[*]}` expands to a **single word** with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS special variable, and `${name[@]}` expands **each element** of name to a separate word.

Example:

```
aws_user_roles=( a "b c" d )

for i in "${aws_user_roles[*]}"; do echo $i; done
a b c d

for i in "${aws_user_roles[@]}"; do echo $i; done
a
b c
d
```